# Android list setSelection() is not pointing to the correct item

Tags: java, android, search, android-listview

My problem is that the `setSelection()` method is not pointing to the correct item. I am creating a search function where the user can click on the search result and then main list is scrolled to the selected item.

If the number of items on the list is small, from 1 - 100 says. It does not have any problems. When it become large, more than 20,000. It points to the incorrect item on the list.

Is this a problem with my code? Its simply a `setSelection()` code, I also put an index on the search result so I could compare whether my search index is equal to the list index.

The code is fairly simple,

```
listView.setSelection(SearchActivity.selectedSearchIndex);
```

`SearchActivity.selectedSearchIndex` contains the index of the selected item displayed on the search list.

Thanks

Comment: show your code or expect downvotes and question closed

Answer (score 0):

If you post some code it would be helpful. However, having had issues with this in the past I know using postDelayed usually fixes it:

```
yourListView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        yourListView.setSelection(yourPosition);
    }
}, 50L);
```